# Why are some of the functions missing when I call a module I created from another script?

Tags: python, function, module, wing-ide

I'm working with a module I created a while ago, where I have a bunch of functions I keep re-using. Today, I added a new one but when I try to call it from another script, I got the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute NameOfMyFunction".

The way I'm calling the functions is like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/temp/Volpe_Final_Project/ReUsable")
import GRHE_proj  as GRHE
output=GRHE.TimeDeltaToTime(data)
```

My module "GRHE_proj" has several functions, as you can see in this screenshot (I'm using WingWare):
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duwme.png

But when I import the module in my other script I only get 3 options:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIllG.png

Any ideas of why some of the functions are being omitted?

Comment: Does your module contain multiple files or only one file?

Comment: It is all written in a single .py  file

Comment: What do you get when you do `dir(GRHE)`?

Comment: Are you pointing to the right place? You append C:/temp/Volpe_Final_Project/ReUsable to path but your spapshot says you are editing something in dropbox. Try `print GRHE_proj.__file__` to see what you imported. You may want to `sys.path.insert(0, "C:/temp/Volpe_Final_Project/ReUsable")` to put your stuff at the front of the search path and avoid stale copies. Also, you may have to re-enter the interpreter because python only imports a module once.

Comment: .....
I feel so stupid... How didn't I see THAT? I didn't realize I had the file repeated twice in my computer. That's so dangerous/stupid.
@tdelaney THANKS!

ps: should I delete this question? Or let a moderator do it?

Comment: @Noebyus - I'll write it as the answer. Appending instead of inserting is a common mistake so I think the question / answer is legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not importing the module you think you are. Print GRHE_proj.__file__ to see what you got. When you are importing a module that is not in the standard library path, it's generally better to insert your path at the front of the list instead of appending it to the back so that you don't risk importing a different version of the module that is in the path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/temp/Volpe_Final_Project/ReUsable")
import GRHE_proj  as GRHE
output=GRHE.TimeDeltaToTime(data)
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good tip. What is the difference between inserting and appending?

Comment: @Noebyus - Inserting puts your path at the top of the search list so that it is searched before the other paths when python is looking for a module file.